# Can you trigger an Angular Input setter with a Subject repeatedly?

Tags: angular, rxjs, binding

I want to trigger an @Input setter without a value, thus using RxJS' `Subject()`.
However, this only emits one time, apparently because no value has changed.

**How can I get the input to trigger anytime I call `next()` on the subject?**

Parent component

```
fromEvent(window, 'keydown').subscribe((res: KeyboardEvent) => {
  this.save$.next();
});

// HTML
<some-component [save]="(save$ | async)" />
```

some-component

```
@Input() set save() {
  console.log('save'); // only fires one time
}
```

This setup only triggers the first time. All subsequent times do not trigger the binding.

EDIT: one way to do this is add a new value each time.

`this.save$.next({});`

But that defats the purpose of the question to simply trigger the setter (w no value)

Comment: I think Angular calls the setter only when the value in the template changes

Comment: But what is the point? You could subscribe ín that component to the obs and do whatever you want. You dont need an input for that.

Comment: I think you're looking at this from the wrong angle. To achieve what you're after (having a save event sent from one component to trigger the save somewhere else, you should either use ViewChild from the parent, to have a reference onto the child and call save directly OR if the component is further away than a parent/child relationship, have a service with an observable that the parent can `next` into the child subscribe to

Comment: Another way would be to have instead an `Observable` as an  `@Input`, for example `save$`, and give it your `save$` subject and subscribe to it on set. It means however that you have to handle the subscription and unsubscription inside your component. Plus, maxime1992 suggestions seem cleaner.

Answer (score -4):

well you could just do:

```js
fromEvent(window, 'keydown').subscribe(this.save$)
```